# Make file available for download outside working/project directory with bottle py

Tags: python, html, download, bottle

How to make a file available for download in bottle when the file is in your file system root directory. For instance, inside the 'media' dir of an ubuntu operatiing system?

python:

```
#bottle 0.12.10
@route('/download/<filename:path>')
def staticdownloadfile(filename):
    return bottle.static_file(filename, root='/media', download=filename)
```

html:

```
<a href="/static/media/somefile.extension">download here</a>
```

The above approach does not work ? 404 not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html file you should use another link:

```
<a href="/download/somefile.extension">download here</a>
```

because in app you have defined:

```
@route('/download/<filename:path>')
```